# Write a program that returns number of decimal digits in the given input string

Tags: java

Write a program that returns number of decimal digits in the given input string.

ex :

Input: `2345abc423`

output: 7

This is my code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String s = input.nextLine();

int len = s.length();
int numbers = 0 ;

for(int i=0; i < len; i++){
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    int num = (int) c;

    while(num <= 57 && num >= 48){
        System.out.println(numbers);
        numbers++;
    }
}

System.out.print(numbers);
```

/////

sorry because my question wasn't obvious

my program always return 0 , not the number of decimal digits

thanks @Keppil i tried `if` and it worked

thanks

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: Note that the method `Character.isDigit` might be useful.

Comment: In what way is this code not working the way you expect it to?

Comment: okay, is there something wrong with your code?

Comment: Most likely a homework assignment, possibly copied and pasted. Someone call an admin.

Comment: @user2958652: We don't police those things here. The community would react accordingly if it is a blatant no-effort givemethecodez questions.

Comment: Oh, gotcha, that is a different web site I am thinking of then.

Comment: my program always return 0 , not the number of decimal digits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program will never exit the `while` loop since the condition never changes. You should just use an `if` instead:

```
if (num <= 57 && num >= 48) {
    System.out.println(numbers);
    numbers++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution that abuses regex:

```
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\D", "").length());
```